# coming from panel to a double gang with two gfci nec approved?

Tags: gfci

Everyone has been so nice but never answered my questioned. Can I have a double gfci coming from a panel to a double gang box in a laundry room using line side only nec approved? Why? Because I want both to be independent in case one shuts down and doesn't affect the other.

Comment: It sure sounded like @threephaseeel answered it.

Comment: I thought I had also answered it. Yes it can be done.

Comment: @EdBeal Yes, yes you did.